# Исключение типа System.IndexOutOfRangeException при получении из анонимного канала

Tags: c#, массивы

Массиву str задаётся размер N. Затем массив по анонимному каналу передаётся в другой поток.
И, когда из анон.канала происходит считывание элементов массива, происходит исключение IndexOutOfRange.
Код передачи элементов из анон.канал массиву приведён ниже

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                        {
                            numII[i] = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                        }
```

UPDATE2 : Теперь привожу действительно полный код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;

namespace ParaProgBv2
{
    class Program
    {
        static public Stream outStream;
        static public Stream inStream;
        public static AnonymousPipeServerStream pipeServer;
        public static AnonymousPipeClientStream pipeClient;
        static public string pipeHandle;
        static int mode;
        static bool stop = false;
        static object thisLock = new object();
        static int com;
        static int N;
        static string S;
        static int k = 0;
        static float[] num = new float[N];
        static string[] str = new string[3];
        static string[] strII = new string[3];
        static float[] numII = new float[N];
        public static void Second()
        {
            pipeClient = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, pipeHandle);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
            while (!stop)
            {
                lock (thisLock)
                {
                    //string buffer = "";
                    //buffer = sr.ReadLine();
                    int tmp = mode;
                    if (tmp == 1)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                        {
                            strII[i] = Convert.ToString(sr.ReadLine());
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine($"Message read ({DateTime.Now}): {strII[0]} {strII[1]} {strII[2]}");
                        Console.WriteLine("Обработка строки");
                        int sim = Convert.ToInt32(strII[2]);
                        string tmpStr = strII[0].Substring(0, sim) + strII[1];
                        Console.WriteLine(tmpStr);
                    }
                    else if (tmp == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Обработка чисел");
                        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                        {
                            numII[i] = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine()); //Здесь возникает исключение
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Message read ({DateTime.Now}): {numII[i]}");
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                        {
                            if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0 && numII[i] > 0)
                            {
                                k++;
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine($"В заданном массиве {k} положительных элементов с чётными индексами");
                    }
                    else if (tmp == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Завершение");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ага, такой команды точно нет");
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1);            
            }
            sr.Close();
        }
        static void intCheck(out int N) //Проверка ввода целочисленной переменной
        {
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out N))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Некорректный ввод");
            }
        }
        static void floatCheck(out float N) //Проверка ввода численной переменной с плавающей точкой
        {
            while (!float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out N))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Некорректный ввод");
            }
        }
        static void stringCheck(out string S) //Проверка ввода номера символа для объединения строк
        {
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out N))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Некорректный ввод");
            }
            S = Convert.ToString(N);
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Thread th2 = new Thread(() => Second());
            pipeServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out);
            outStream = pipeServer;
            pipeHandle = pipeServer.GetClientHandleAsString();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outStream);
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            while (!stop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите цифру 1 для того что бы выполнить задание с обработкой строк");
                Console.WriteLine("Введите цифру 2 для того что бы выполнить задание с обработкой массива");
                Console.WriteLine("Введите цифру 3 для того, чтобы выйти");
                if (!th2.IsAlive)
                {
                    th2.Start();
                }
                lock (thisLock)
                {
                    intCheck(out com);
                    if (com != 1 && com != 2 && com != 3) { com = 4; }
                    mode = com;
                    switch (com)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите буквенную строку 1");
                            str[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите буквенную строку 2");
                            str[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                            /*Вставка одной строки в другую с заданного символа*/
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите номер символа, после которого будет замена");
                            stringCheck(out str[2]);
                            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(str[i]);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            /*Подсчет числа положительных элементов с четными индексами*/
                            Console.Write("Введите размер массива = ");
                            intCheck(out N);
                            num = new float[N];
                            Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы массива:");
                            for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
                            {
                                Console.Write("{0} элемент = ", i + 1);
                                floatCheck(out num[i]);
                                sw.WriteLine(num[i]);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            stop = true;
                            sw.WriteLine(com);
                            break;
                            case 4:
                                Console.WriteLine("Нет такой комманды");
                                break;
                    }
                }
            }
            sw.Close();
            th2.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S заранее прошу прощения за внешний вид кода, изучаю шарп первый месяц и до форматирования кода пока не дошёл.

Comment: Поглядите на код, что вы приели. Разве из него можно что либо понять вообще? Вы итерируете по какой то переменной `str.Length`, но при этом почему то записываете в `numII[i]`. Вот вам похожий код - `if (a) b.Invoke(c[i]);` - попробуйте догадаться, что в этом коде не так и вы поймете, что я имею ввиду. Приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), тогда может что то прояснится.

Comment: Код же можете отформатировать, чтобы было его читать удобно? Или я могу это сделать за вас, если не получается. Только скажите.

Comment: Писать учусь полгода, не особо понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под форматированием кода

Comment: Что такое ПОТОК? Я не понимаю пока, как работает ваш код. В какой строке кода возникает исключение? Пометьте в своем коде это строчку комментарием `// здесь возникает исключение`

Comment: То, что вы привели, не является самодостаточным примером. Нельзя этот ваш код скопировать к себе в студию и запустить, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. Попробуйте почитать ссылку, что я вам привел, и вот эту [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), потратье время, чтобы переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы тот, кто его прочитает, смог понять и воспроизвести вашу проблему. Просто выкидывание кусков кода делу не поможет.

Comment: @aepot искренне прошу прощения, убрал куски кода и предоставил полную версию.

Comment: @ИннокентийМихайлов форматирование кода - просто нормальные отступы, как в студии. А не так как вы изначально запостили, с пробелами на половину страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не создаете массив `NumII` заданной длины. Исключение возникает из-за того, что длина массива на момент выполнения той самой строки `0`.

1. Уберите инициализацию массивов в глобальной области, потому что на момент инициализации `N` равно `0`. Это по факту вас только сбило с толку.

```
static float[] num;
static float[] numII;
```

2. Вот здесь вот так

```cs
Console.Write("Введите размер массива = ");
intCheck(out N);
num = new float[N];
numII = new float[N]; // добавьте эту строку
```

Comment: Поклон вам, благодаря таким людям, как вы, я всё ещё продолжаю учиться программировать.